# Phonegap: Google Maps' SearchBox / Autocomplete NOT Working on iOS / Mobile

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cordova, phonegap-build

I am using Google Maps APIv3, jQuery 1.9.1, JQuery Mobile 1.3.1, and Phonegap 2.9.0 and have made a fiddle with my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/vkpWK/   I believe there must be something going on in these 3 lines of code:

```
// Assign Search Box
input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (document.getElementById('searchTextField')),
searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

// Event Listener - Move the Map on Search Results
google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {
```

In Phonegap this code works, but when you are presented with the SearchBox's dropdown list of suggestions, you cannot click on them.  Clicking on them does nothing.  I am looking for a way to have the clicks on the suggestions actually fire the 'places_changed' event.

To make things complicated, here is the kicker.  This code works.  It works as is on desktops and on iOS / Android.  You can click on the search results and it works as intended, the map will update to the newly searched location.  It does not, however, work for me in Phonegap.  I have a bad feeling that this is somehow a CSS issue or maybe some other JS listener is not allowing this to happen.  How can I test this theory?

As an alternative, I have tested using google.maps.places.Autocomplete instead of google.maps.places.SearchBox, but it did not help.

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, lemme give it a try ! :)

Comment: pennstump, any luck with this issue? I just ran across it today. Works on the desktop, android (using cordova), but not on IOS7 (using cordova).

Answer (score -1):

I made it working after adding this in my `index.html's` `<head>`:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Also if you are able to see very small fonts and UI, try replacing this `<meta>` :

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />`

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to give it a shot.  So, you added the jQuery UI Package??

Comment: Unfortunately, his did not fix things for me on any of my test devices.  Thank you, though.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't work in my Phonegap app.  Thanks again for the input, though.  I've been forced to work around this and just not have the dropdown suggestions.

Comment: No, this doesn't help, any solution for this?